# the requested operation requires sql clr context

Tags: c#, mysql

I am getting an error while connecting to the sql from my cs file. I am trying to create CLR functions in c# without using any IDE which is the requirement. I need to access the database to get some value. Following is the code to connect to my database in c#.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count' FROM customer_master with (nolock)", conn);
    SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd);
    return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

}
```

but I am getting the following error:

"The requested operation requires a SqlClr context, which is only available when running in the Sql Server process". If i use pipe i don't know how to convert that to an int value. Any suggestions please....

Comment: Does your SQL statement work on its own?  I thought I remembered reading somewhere that MySQL doesn't support "WITH".

Comment: Just so I understand, you're trying to use SQL CLR with MySQL? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think it's mysql, @user1031746 did you mean MS SQL?

Comment: @DaveShaw Right, he's probably got it tagged wrong.  I should have made that connection when I saw him using the SqlConnection object.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this Blog](http://pierrerebours.com/blog/context-connection-and-sqlclr-functions) post, try it like this, with the `SQLConnection` not in a using. The `SQLCommand` is Disposable and should be in a using though.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true") ;
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand( 
        "SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count' FROM customer_master with (nolock)", conn))
{ 
    conn.Open(); 
    return (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();      
}
```

---

**I wrote the below first, but I think the above is the answer, I'm leaving struck out in case it is relevant.**

---

<strike>A `ContextConnection` is a connection back down the existing open connection that the SQL calling the CLR function is using. 
To use a SQL CLR Function with a `ContextConnection` you have to call it from inside a SQL Statement.</strike>

e.g. (where `CLRConvert` is my CLR function that connects back to my database and performs a query and converts stuff).

```
select dbo.CLRConvert(Data) from MyTables;
```

If you need to call it outside of here, you will need a proper [connection string](http://connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008).